# Create a count of Column A to distribute by Column B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get a count of the number of trials by state that took place in the United States. The information I need comes from the nct_id, state and country columns. I am in pgAdmin on a Macbook Pro. A small sample is below:

```
nct_id        state       country
NCT04832854   Illinois    United States
NCT04832851   Michigan    United States
NCT04832802   California  United States
NCT04832813   Naples      Italy
NCT04832813   Illinois    United States
```

I want to group the nct_id's by state, but only if the country is 'United States'. I have this so far. I get an error saying ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 3: COUNT(nct_id) AS Count_Trials. I'm not sure what the syntax error is here though.

```
SELECT nct_id, state
FROM facilities
COUNT(nct_id) AS Count_Trials
GROUP BY state
HAVING Country = 'United States'
```

I'd like the output to be like the below:

```
state      Count_Trials
Illinois   2
Michigan   1
California 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer below

```
SELECT  state, count(nct_id) count_trials
FROM facilities
where country  = 'United States'  group by state, country order by count(nct_id) desc
```

Test

```
select   state , count(nct_id) count_trials from (            
select 'NCT04832854' nct_id  ,  'Illinois' state,    'United States'country union all
select 'NCT04832851' ,  'Michigan',    'United States' union all
select 'NCT04832802' ,  'California',  'United States' union all
select 'NCT04832813' ,  'Naples',      'Italy' union all
select 'NCT04832813' ,  'Illinois',    'United States'
) a where country  = 'United States'  group by state, country order by count(nct_id) desc
```